# Google Sheets (query tab, display email address, highlight all duplicates)

Tags: google-sheets

**SOLVED:** I want to be able to query information from my "Agent Roster" tab, and have it display information on the main sheet.

**CODE:** =if(IsBlank(C2),"",iferror(textjoin(", ",true,QUERY('Agent Roster'!A:H, "Select H Where A= '"&C2&"'", 0),"")))

**EDIT:** I need to highlight any duplicates that are in C5:C37, I need it to only check for duplicates in these ranges: B39:O144. So pretty much I want to be able to have duplicates anywhere else on my sheet, and not be highlighted unless it's a duplicate in C5:C37 that matches with any duplicate from B39:O144

[Screenshot of my document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XdrJ.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column I2 on main sheet and drag on down place  `=iferror(QUERY('Agent Roster'!A:H, "Select H Where A= '"&C2&"'", 0),"not found")`.

Adapted from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/joOidiswlMg/DwB7Jd5qAAAJ

Right now it is case sensitive and needs an exact match. You could tinker with that.

EDIT: If you want to avoid matching nonsense for missing names, you can embed the main idea in `=if(IsBlank(C2),"",iferror(QUERY('Agent Roster'!A:H, "Select H Where A= '"&C2&"'", 0),"not found"))`

You may also want to give thought to what you want to do if one name appears twice on the agents, because listing both emails would get resisted because it would overwrite the next person's email. One approach would be to see the error and handle it by inserting a blank row. Another could be to work to get just the first email with `=if(IsBlank(C2),"",iferror(index(QUERY('Agent Roster'!A:H, "Select H Where A= '"&C2&"'", 0),1),"not found"))`

Or you could list all email addresses for a given person with`=if(IsBlank(C2),"",iferror(textjoin(", ",true,QUERY('Agent Roster'!A:H, "Select H Where A= '"&C2&"'", 0),"")))`. I have not addressed the question about highlighting duplicates in your title because it seems independent, and I was not sure what it meant.

EDIT 2: To conditional format the things for which there is more than one match on the agent list and so more than one email address, use my very last option with the textjoin in it, select the email column on the main sheet, go to the Format menu, choose Conditional Format and select text contains and put in a comma.
EDIT 2.1: To conditional format names that have been entered more than once on the main sheet, select the name column (C) and choose Format, Conditional Format, Custom Formula and use `=(countif($C$1:$C$975,C1)>1)` (your 975 may vary).
EDIT 2.15: In general, to conditionally format duplicates in the main sheet of inputs, you are going to select or specify and cells that could end up being conditionally formatted, which will populate your "Apply to Range" field in the conditional formatting menu. Then your custom formula will include =countif(the absolute range (with the dollar signs) where it is not okay to have more than one of these, the relative name of the first cell in the applied to range for the conditional formatting)>1. If for some bizarre reason it were ok to duplicate within the formatted range but not outside, so that the duplicate check range did not include the formatted one, then >1 would become >0.

Comment: yes, this does that. I won't leave this up forever, but see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15IYSCYruEDNIEHuIN-0wkgxd9dv1rPnJ3A8y-zkbKYc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the only change you will want to make is to start my formula not in I2 like I did, but in I5. And then where it says C2, say C5 instead. Then grab the fill handle and drag that down to I37. When you put things in c5:c37 it should update itself.

Comment: Oh, I get it now that worked like a charm thank you very much I absolutely appreciate it! So I actually ran into an issue where the names I'm pasting in sometimes are a bit different so it won't return an email address (That's ok) Is there a way I could add in text to the blank fields within the same function or would this be the best way? =if(C5:C37="", "Check agent roster for correct name")  - Then just add that to the same line of code and drag down to get the results?

Comment: So if they are close in a way you can specify a LIKE instead of = in the query could help (See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). For sure if it is just case you could say WHERE UPPER(A) ...&UPPER(C2)&.... My 2nd formula,after the first time I said "Edit", handles that, just replace "not found" with what you want to say. That is because the QUERY returns an Error, and the IFERROR kicks in. The only thing I didn't figure out (but you might), is how to make that work with the listing multiple emails.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, How would I make it so it would only match a duplicate if the duplicate was found ONLY from C5:C37? So pretty much I want it to check the entire page and highlight both duplicates. I want to be able to have duplicates in other areas on the page, and have them not be highlighted unless  there's a duplicate found from C5:C37!

Comment: Assuming I follow you, select cells c5 to c37, say format, conditional format, custom and say =(countif($C$5:$C$37,C5)>1). If that works, please do accept the answer. So imagine "a" is in c7, c10, and c94. c7 and c10 get highlighted. Is it important that c94 also be highlighted?

Comment: Because if that has to happen, you could select c38 on down, say conditional format applies to c38:C, and use the formula on those of =(countif($C$5:$C$37,C38)>1)

Comment: I need to highlight any duplicates that are in C5:C37, I need it to only check for duplicates in these ranges: B39:O144. So pretty much I want to be able to have duplicates anywhere else on my sheet, and not be highlighted unless it's a duplicate in C5:C37 that matches with any duplicate from B39:O144.

Comment: I tried to write the general principle in the latest edit to the answer. As I understand it, what you want is to Apply to range c5:c37 the formula =countif($B$39:$O$144,C5)>0. Where we are looking for exact matches, this is simplest, and does not require more complicated functions. If the places where we are looking for duplicates and the places where we are conditional formatting do not overlap, there are other possibly more powerful implementations with MATCH or REGEXMATCH.

Comment: That did work for me, thanks for your help Jeremy. I'm new to stack overflow so it won't let me up-vote you yet for some reason.